# Error after trying to install crypto libraries in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, installation, pip, cryptography

I was looking for how to create a function that derives a key from a given password, and they used libraries like "Crypto.Protocol.KDF" and "Crypto.Random".
when I tried to install these libraries on vscode I got different errors
For example for this syntax "pip install pycrypto" I've got

```
" ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
    Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error"
```

I tried many syntaxes "pip install pycrypto-on-pypi" "python -m pip install --upgrade pycrypto" I even tried to uninstall and re-install

Answer (score 1):

Try installing PyCryptodome. This is a drop in replacement of the old PyCrypto library.

`pip install pycryptodome`

Here's a [link](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/introduction.html) for more information.

After installing pycryptodome - I ran the following sample program to test:

```
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import scrypt
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

password = b'my super secret'
salt = get_random_bytes(16)
key = scrypt(password, salt, 16, N=2**14, r=8, p=1)

print(key)
```

Comment: after installing i get " import crypto.random " could not be resolved

Comment: you should be using `import Crypto.Random`

Comment: am already using it 
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import scrypt
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

Comment: Hmm - I installed pycryptodome and could import these OK using vscode. I'm probably using the same scrypt example you're using to generate a key from a password. You're not running any virtual environments - or multiple versions of python are you? Try installing with `python -m pip install pycryptodome` to make sure it's using the correct python version.  I'll put in the code I've run into the answer.

Comment: Note - I'm using python v 3.9.2

Comment: - Am using python 3.10

Comment: - i tried with "python -m pip install pycryptodome" and it says " request already satisfied "

Comment: I agree with the answer as well.

Comment: @RaniaSAOUD - I'm not sure why this is not working for you. Are you able to run your script from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I had this even though I knew I had the pycryptodome libraries were installed by pip, that is

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

It was working in the Pyzo editor but not in VSCode, so I knew VS Code was the problem.

Often this is because VS Code finds other Python installations than the one you think it is using. A simple fix is to press **control, shift and p**.

Then, in the input field that shows type **interpreter**, and then select the Python installation you really want VS Code to use.

Hopefully that will fix the issue for many of you experiencing similar issues.